# SQLite foreign key in android/

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

i am working on Android 2.2

i have created two table and second table have the foreign key as a primary key of first table 
but at the time of insertion the foreign key column remain blank.. 
here's the tables..

```
public static final String KEY_Username = "username";
public static final String KEY_Password = "password";
public static final String KEY_SITE = "site";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String SERVICE_OREDER = "Service_Order";
private static final String ERROR_CODE = "Error_Code";
private static final String SERVICE_OPERATION = "Service_Operation";
private static final String COMPONENT = "Component";
private static final String TECHNICIAN = "Technician";



//------------------------Service Order Table---------------------
private static final String KEY_SERVICE_ORDER_RECORD_NO="service_order_record_no";
private static final String KEY_OREDR_TYPE="order_type";
private static final String KEY_PRIORITY="priority";
private static final String KEY_PLANT="plant";
private static final String KEY_FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION="functional_location";
private static final String KEY_EQUIPMENT_DESC="equipment_description";
private static final String KEY_EQUIPMENT_NO="equipment_no";
private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_ID="customer_id";
private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME="customer_name";
private static final String KEY_WIND_SPEED="wind_speed";
private static final String KEY_TOTAL_PRODUCTION="total_production";
private static final String KEY_NCR="NCR";
private static final String KEY_TOTAL_GRID_HR="total_grid_hours";
private static final String KEY_TOTAL_OPERATION_HR="total_operation_hours";
private static final String KEY_SERVICE_VISIT="service_visit_p_year";
private static final String KEY_ORDER_DESC="order_description";
private static final String KEY_ERRORCODE_START_DT="error_code_start_date_and_time";
private static final String KEY_MALFUNCTION_START_DT="malfunction_start_date_and_time";
private static final String KEY_MALFUNCTION_END_DT="malfunction_end_date_and_time";

private static final String SERVICE_ORDER_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+SERVICE_OREDER+" ("+KEY_SERVICE_ORDER_RECORD_NO+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,"+ 
        ""+KEY_OREDR_TYPE+" TEXT NOT NULL , "+KEY_PRIORITY+" TEXT, "+KEY_PLANT+" TEXT, "+KEY_FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION+" TEXT, "+
        ""+KEY_EQUIPMENT_DESC+" TEXT,"+KEY_EQUIPMENT_NO+" TEXT, "+KEY_CUSTOMER_ID+" TEXT, "+KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME+" TEXT,"+
        ""+KEY_WIND_SPEED+" TEXT, "+KEY_TOTAL_PRODUCTION+" TEXT, "+KEY_NCR+" TEXT,"+KEY_TOTAL_GRID_HR+" TEXT,"+
        ""+KEY_TOTAL_OPERATION_HR+" TEXT, "+KEY_SERVICE_VISIT+" TEXT, "+KEY_ORDER_DESC+" TEXT, "+
        ""+KEY_ERRORCODE_START_DT+" TEXT, "+KEY_MALFUNCTION_START_DT+" TEXT, "+KEY_MALFUNCTION_END_DT+" TEXT)"; 



//------------------------Error Code Table---------------------
private static final String KEY_ERROR_CODE_REC_NO ="error_code_record_no";
private static final String KEY_CODE_GROUP ="code_group";
private static final String KEY_CODE ="code";
private static final String KEY_SERVICE_ORDER_REC_NO="service_order_record_no";

private static final String ERROR_CODE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+ERROR_CODE+" ("+KEY_ERROR_CODE_REC_NO+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,"+ 
        ""+KEY_CODE_GROUP+" TEXT,"+KEY_CODE+" TEXT, "+KEY_SERVICE_ORDER_REC_NO+" INTEGER,"+
        "FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_SERVICE_ORDER_REC_NO+") REFERENCES "+SERVICE_OREDER+"("+KEY_SERVICE_ORDER_RECORD_NO+") ON DELETE CASCADE )";


//-----------------------Service Operation Table-----------------
private static final String KEY_SERVICE_OPE_REC_NO ="service_operation_record_no";
private static final String KEY_OPE_ACTIVITY ="operation_activity";
private static final String KEY_CONTROLLING_KEY ="controlling_key";
private static final String KEY_ACTION_TYPE ="action_type";
private static final String KEY_LONG_TEXT ="long_text";
private static final String KEY_WORK_HPM="work_hours_p_min";
private static final String KEY_SO_UNIT="unit";
private static final String KEY_NO_RESORCE ="no_of_resources";
private static final String KEY_ERROR_CODE_REC="error_code_record_no";

private static final String SERVICE_OPERATION_TABLE_CREATE ="CREATE TABLE "+SERVICE_OPERATION+" ("+KEY_SERVICE_OPE_REC_NO+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,"+KEY_OPE_ACTIVITY+" TEXT, "+KEY_CONTROLLING_KEY+" TEXT, "+KEY_ACTION_TYPE+" TEXT, "+KEY_LONG_TEXT+" TEXT ,"+KEY_WORK_HPM+" TEXT, "+KEY_SO_UNIT+" TEXT , "+KEY_NO_RESORCE+" TEXT ,"+KEY_ERROR_CODE_REC+" INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_ERROR_CODE_REC+") REFERENCES "+ERROR_CODE+"("+KEY_ERROR_CODE_REC_NO+") ON DELETE CASCADE )";


// ------------------------Component Table----------------------
private static final String KEY_COMP_REC_NO = "component_record_no";
private static final String KEY_COMP_NO= "component_no";
private static final String KEY_COMP_DESC = "component_description";
private static final String KEY_COMP_ID  = "component_id";
private static final String KEY_REQ_QTY = "required_quantity";
private static final String KEY_UOM = "UoM";
private static final String KEY_ITEM_CAT = "item_category";
private static final String Key_OPE_ACT = "operation_activity";
private static final String KEY_STOR_LOC ="storage_location";
private static final String KEY_VAL_TYPE ="valuation_type";
private static final String KEY_SER_OPR_REC_NO = "service_operation_record_no";
private static final String KEY_SER_NO_ARRY ="serial_nos_array";

private static final String COMP_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "+COMPONENT+" ( "+KEY_COMP_REC_NO+" INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT  not null,"+
                                                ""+KEY_COMP_NO+" TEXT, "+KEY_COMP_DESC+" TEXT, "+KEY_COMP_ID+"  TEXT, "+KEY_REQ_QTY+" TEXT,"+
                                                ""+KEY_UOM+" TEXT, "+KEY_ITEM_CAT+" TEXT , "+Key_OPE_ACT+" TEXT ,"+KEY_STOR_LOC+" TEXT,"+
                                                ""+KEY_VAL_TYPE+" TEXT ,"+KEY_SER_OPR_REC_NO+" INTEGER,"+KEY_SER_NO_ARRY+" TEXT,"+ 
                                                "FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_SER_OPR_REC_NO+") REFERENCES "+SERVICE_OPERATION+"("+KEY_SERVICE_OPE_REC_NO+") ON DELETE CASCADE)";

//------------------------Technician Table---------------------
private static final String KEY_TECH_REC_NO ="technician_record_no";
private static final String KEY_TECH ="technician";
private static final String KEY_WORK_HM ="work_hours_p_min";
private static final String KEY_UNIT ="unit";
private static final String KEY_DATETIME="date_and_time";
private static final String KEY_SERVICE_OP_REC_NO="service_operation_record_no";

private static final String TECH_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TECHNICIAN+" ("+KEY_TECH_REC_NO+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,"+
                                                ""+KEY_TECH+" TEXT,"+KEY_WORK_HM+" TEXT, "+KEY_UNIT+" TEXT, "+KEY_DATETIME+" TEXT ,"+
                                                ""+KEY_SERVICE_OP_REC_NO+" INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_SERVICE_OP_REC_NO+") REFERENCES "+SERVICE_OPERATION+"("+KEY_SERVICE_OPE_REC_NO+") ON DELETE CASCADE )";


public SuzlonDBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public SuzlonDBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(SERVICE_ORDER_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(ERROR_CODE_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(SERVICE_OPERATION_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(COMP_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(TECH_TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


//------------------------------Insert into Service Order--------------------

public long insertServiceOrder(ServiceOrder serviceOrder){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_OREDR_TYPE, serviceOrder.getOrderType());
        values.put(KEY_PRIORITY, serviceOrder.getPriority());
        values.put(KEY_PLANT, serviceOrder.getPlant());
        values.put(KEY_FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION, serviceOrder.getFunctionalLocation());
        values.put(KEY_EQUIPMENT_DESC, serviceOrder.getEquipmentDescription());
        values.put(KEY_EQUIPMENT_NO, serviceOrder.getEquipmentNo());
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, serviceOrder.getCustomerID());
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME, serviceOrder.getCustomerName());
        values.put(KEY_WIND_SPEED, serviceOrder.getWindSpeed());
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL_PRODUCTION, serviceOrder.getTotalProduction());
        values.put(KEY_NCR, serviceOrder.getNCR());
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL_GRID_HR, serviceOrder.getTotalGridHour());
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL_OPERATION_HR, serviceOrder.getTotalOperationHours());
        values.put(KEY_SERVICE_VISIT, serviceOrder.getServiceVisit());
        values.put(KEY_ORDER_DESC, serviceOrder.getOrderDescription());
        values.put(KEY_ERRORCODE_START_DT, serviceOrder.getErrorCodeStartDT());
        values.put(KEY_MALFUNCTION_START_DT, serviceOrder.getMalfunctionStartDT());
        values.put(KEY_MALFUNCTION_END_DT, serviceOrder.getMalfunctionEndDT());

        Long row = db.insert(SERVICE_OREDER, null, values);
        db.close();
    return row;


}

//-------------------------------Insert into Error Code-------------------------

public long insertErrorCode(DefectDamageCode defectDamage){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CODE_GROUP, defectDamage.getCodeGroups());
        values.put(KEY_CODE, defectDamage.getCodes());


        Long row = db.insert(ERROR_CODE, null, values);
        db.close();
    return row;
}


//--------------------------------Insert into Service Operation----------------------

public long insertServiceOperation(AddServiceOperation serviceOperation){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_OPE_ACTIVITY, serviceOperation.getOperationActivity());
        values.put(KEY_CONTROLLING_KEY, serviceOperation.getControllingKey());
        values.put(KEY_ACTION_TYPE, serviceOperation.getActivityType());
        values.put(KEY_LONG_TEXT, serviceOperation.getLongText());
        values.put(KEY_WORK_HPM, serviceOperation.getWorkHM());
        values.put(KEY_SO_UNIT, serviceOperation.getUnit());
        values.put(KEY_NO_RESORCE, serviceOperation.getNoOfResources());


        Long row = db.insert(SERVICE_OPERATION, null, values);
        db.close();
    return row;
}


//---------------------------Insert into Component------------------------------

public long insertComponent(AddComponent addComponent){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_COMP_NO, addComponent.getComponentNo());
        values.put(KEY_COMP_DESC, addComponent.getComponentDescription());
        values.put(KEY_COMP_ID, addComponent.getCommponentID());
        values.put(KEY_REQ_QTY, addComponent.getRequiredQty());
        values.put(KEY_UOM, addComponent.getUOM());
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_CAT, addComponent.getItemCategory());
        values.put(Key_OPE_ACT, addComponent.getOperationActivityComponent());
        values.put(KEY_STOR_LOC, addComponent.getStorageLocation());
        values.put(KEY_VAL_TYPE, addComponent.getValuationType());
        //values.put(KEY_SER_NO_ARRY, );


        Long row = db.insert(COMPONENT, null, values);
        db.close();
    return row;
}


//-------------------------------Insert into Technician-----------------------------
public long insertTechnician(AddTechnician addTechnician){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TECH, addTechnician.getTechnician());
        values.put(KEY_WORK_HM, addTechnician.getWorkHMTechnician());
        values.put(KEY_UNIT, addTechnician.getUnitTechnician());
        values.put(KEY_DATETIME, addTechnician.getDateTimeTechnician());

        Long row = db.insert(TECHNICIAN, null, values);
        db.close();
    return row;
}
```

}

do i need to provide it manually or it will manage by db..???

pplz help

thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to enforce ForeignKeys, you need to execute following sql statement each time you open database connection:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
```

Afterwards, you are ready to use `db` object in your usual way.

Comment: thanks waqas.. but i tried that already it dint work.. let me add all my dbhelper class..

Comment: Foreign key tables will remain blank. Because foreign key is supposed to restrict the records whose reference is not available in primary tables. So once you add a record in foreign key table, it will first verify its primary key with the primary table's primary key and then allow the insertion. If it fails to do so, you cant enter a record.

Comment: In your case, you need to use [last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) to get the id of last insert record and use this id to add records in child tables.

Comment: if ur free can u give me a simple demo?? i'm first time using sql.