# Android,Error on table creation in android

Tags: android

I am having two tables in my sqlite database. I want to do manipulations on the tables database based upon the button clicks. When button1 clicks it will insert into pdsource table and on button2 click it will insert into pdreview table.

Button 1 function works fine. But Button2 click creates the problem.

My Table Creation Scripts are

```
CREATE TABLE "pdsource" ("Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,"AudioFileName" 
    TEXT,"AudioFilePath" TEXT,"TextFileName" TEXT,"TextFilePath" TEXT,"DateTime" 
    TEXT,"Duration" TEXT,"Attempts" TEXT)

CREATE TABLE pdreview(
    reviewId     INTEGER, 
    priid Integer, 
    fwords Text,
    Gr Text,
    dslow Text,
    orating Text,
    comments Text,
    FOREIGN KEY(reviewId) REFERENCES pdsource(id)
)
```

I will paste the `LogCat` error here

```
06-17 14:49:22.006: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6423): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: pdreview, db=/data/data/com.first.personalitydevelopment/databases/PersonalityDevelopment.db
06-17 14:49:22.042: E/SQLiteDatabase(6423): Error inserting orating=good Gr=Noun missing fwords=hmm prid=1 dslow=medium comments=Excellent
06-17 14:49:22.042: E/SQLiteDatabase(6423): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: pdreview: , while compiling: INSERT INTO pdreview(orating,Gr,fwords,prid,dslow,comments) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685449/sqlite-foreign-key-in-android

Comment: I guess the table does not exist. msg = no such table: pdreview

Comment: Yes you are correct.At the time of table creation itself it creates the problem.I have check the script for more number of times.But  still it is creating a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second table have not been created.

To check if your table is on the databse you can acces it via adb

Go to your android SDK > plaform-tools directory and execute the command

`>adb shell`

`>sqlite3 /data/data/com.first.personalitydevelopment/databases/PersonalityDevelopment.db`

`>.tables` or `>select * from pdreview`

*The first one returns all tables of your database

If your table is not there it could be due to an script problem, execute your second table script.

If it is not created there you have your error on your script (I don't know if sqlite is sensitive because I see your reference "id" is not "Id", maybe this is the error).

If your table is created succesfully you have to know that you cannot modifiy a previous database created. The first time the database is created it will execute the scripts at your onCreate, later, if you want to update you have two options:

- Your app is on the market: you will have to update the version of your database so android will execute the onUpgrade function, there you will have to drop old tables and execute the new script.
- You are developing: Clear the data via settings and the onCreate will be re-executed (or uninstall app)

Comment: Yes. As you said i have uninstalled and did again.Thanks now its fixed.it works fine.

Comment: Ok :) Consider to accept the answer. However remember to implement the onUpgrade method for future cases.

Comment: Yes.I have implemented that already.Thank you for your timely help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer section 4.3 of the link to create a helper class to manage your DB.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Also, no need to enclose column names with quotes. 
In create statement of pdreview, priid is declared but in insert, you've referenced prid. 
You also need to execute 
 "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" every time you open a database to enable foreign keys.

Check if this works.

Comment: I have enabled foreign keys.And also i have changed the prid.But still its not working.